# Application and Web.api in different projects ajax URI generation inserting the port number of the application and not the web.api

Tags: visual-studio, web

I am having problems addressing my web.api methods from the Application UI JQuery an ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

The application and the web.api are split into different projects. This is an architectural constraint and cannot be altered so please don't answer with put the two in one project.

When I run the project the solution the web.api project is run on one port and the application on another.

Within the ajax call to the web.api action method the port of the ui is placed into the uri for the web.api and hence the web.api action method is never called.

How do I make sure that the correct URI is generated?

So the JQuery in the UI looks like this:

```
        $.ajax({
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "GET",
            "url": "api/products",
            "success": function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    var str = '<li>Product Id: ' + item.Id + ' Stock Code: ' + item.StockCode + '</li>';
                    $('#productId').append(str);
                });
            },
            "error": function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                    var str = '<li>Product Id: ' + data[i].Id + ' Stock Code: ' + data[i].StockCode + '</li>';
                    $('#productId').append(str);
                });
            }
        });
```

The URI that is being requested looks like this:

```
http://localhost:50481/api/products
```

but the web.api is hosted on another port.

Comment: If you want another port, give a full URI instead of just a relative path. (Be aware though that you might run into SOP problems with that setup.)

Comment: Thanks, what is a SOP problem?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

It would appear the answer is in Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/cors